# Combining loops and file redirection

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a script that will prompt the user to enter a file name, request the user to enter four peoples names, then sort the names into the file specified.

Comment: And I'm sure people would try to answer if you had a question and showed them what you had attempted already.

Comment: Well I am a new to scripting and really not sure where to begin

Comment: My question is how is this done? .

Comment: @user2884120: You should at least post some example data and expected output.

Comment: The input would be up to the user.. expected output would be a list of the user input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter filename: " fn
declare -a arr
for ((i=1; i<=4; i++)); do
   read -p "Enter name $i: " n
   arr+=("$n")
done
sort <(printf "%s\n" ${arr[@]}) > "$fn"
```

Comment: Very nice.. the script is a little more complicated than expected but works perfectly.

Comment: Please read about a tutorial on BASH arrays. Also if this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.